# JQueryMobile Theme not applying

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I used JQM's Themeroller to develop a theme for my application. Right now, I'm just trying to get it to work in Chrome.

I have the head of my HTML file set up like so:

```
<head>
    <title>SafeRides</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/SafeRidesTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

and my file director is as follows:

```
Application/
    index.html
    themes/
        SafeRidesTheme.css
        SafeRidesTheme.min.css
        images/
```

Am I just missing something obvious in the layout of my files? If someone could help me realize what's going on here I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using custom theme made by Theme Roller, libraries should be loaded this way.

You should remove jQM defualt style sheet and load jQM structure style sheet before your custom one.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/SafeRidesTheme.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, Omar. I appreciate it :) Oddly enough, after I downloaded the theme from JQM Themeroller, I did exactly what it told me "To use your theme, add it to the head of your page before the jquerey.mobile.structure..." This worked, however.